# VBA - Replacing commas in CSV not inside quotes

Tags: vba

```
  Filename = Dir(Filepath & "\" & "*.csv")
    While Filename <> ""
        SourceFile = Filepath & "\" & Filename
        TargetFile = SavePath & "\" & Replace(Filename, ".csv", ".txt")

        OpenAsUnicode = False

        Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Detect Unicode Files
        Dim Stream: Set Stream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(SourceFile, 1, False)
        intChar1 = Asc(Stream.Read(1))
        intChar2 = Asc(Stream.Read(1))
        Stream.Close
        If intChar1 = 255 And intChar2 = 254 Then
            OpenAsUnicode = True
        End If

        'Get script content
        Set Stream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(SourceFile, 1, 0, OpenAsUnicode)
        arrData = Stream.ReadAll()
        Stream.Close

        'Create output file
        Dim objOut: Set objOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile(TargetFile)
        objOut.Write Replace(Replace(arrData,",", "#|#"), Chr(34), "")  '-- This line is working fine but it is replacing all the commas inside the text qualifier as well..
        objOut.Close

        Filename = Dir

    Wend
```

In the above code the line objOut.Write Replace(Replace(arrData,",", "#|#"), Chr(34), "") is replacing all the commas with #|# including the commas inside string.so I want to replace only commas which are not in double quotes.

File containing the string 
"A","B,C",D

Result I need is 
A#|#B,C#|#D

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: this is one of the first hits on google. please search first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780765/parse-csv-ignoring-commas-inside-string-literals-in-vba

Comment: Thanks 
But the link you provided will change the delimiter for single string
How can I apply this to multiple files in the loop..
I am not really expert in VBA if you could change my code that would be great help...

Comment: change you replace to replace "," with #|# instead of just replacing the ,

Comment: Mathew - sorry I didn't get your answer properly

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? what is the purpose of re-writing the file with the pound signs?

Comment: Client has some SQL procedure to import the data and it will accept only #|# column delimiter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along the line of:

```
objOut.Write Mid(Replace(Replace(arrData,""",""", "#|#"), Chr(34), ""), 2)
```

Basically, this exchanges now `","` for `#|#`. But that's not enough as the file begins with a `"`. So, this one is being eliminated using the `Mid()` function. If the file also ends with a `"` then you would have to adjust that as well.

Based on the speed concerns noted in the comments here is the complete code which I used to test this solution:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Sub ConvertFile()
Dim lngRowNumber As Long
Dim strLineFromFile As String
Dim strSourceFile As String
Dim strDestinationFile As String

strSourceFile = "C:\tmp\Extract.txt"
strDestinationFile = "C:\tmp\Extract_b.txt"

Open strSourceFile For Input As #1
Open strDestinationFile For Output As #2

lngRowNumber = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strLineFromFile
    strLineFromFile = Mid(Replace(strLineFromFile, """,""", "#|#"), 2)
    Write #2, strLineFromFile
    strLineFromFile = vbNullString
Loop

Close #1
Close #2

End Sub
```

The tested file was 350 MB with a bit over 4 million rows. The code completed in less than a minute.

Comment: This won't work. I have file with 10000 lines out of which 3000 lines are having commas inside the double quotes.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of performance you are looking for. But with the above code I was able to convert a 350 MB file with 4.2 million rows in less than a minute.

Comment: See below Line 
COLUMN_TYPE,12,04-Feb-08,121,08-Dec-99,1,121,V,"A,B"
I need results as 
COLUMN_TYPE#|#12#|#04-Feb-08#|#121#|#08-Dec-99#|#1#|#121#|#V#|#A,B

Comment: It seems that you are changing your question. Yet, if you have several different formats in one file (the originally asked parsing situation and this new one) then it will get tricky and you'll have to analyze each row in order to find out which part of the line needs to be replaced and in which format. Anyway, the above solution answers your original question. So, please mark the question as closed.