# writing data from Excel to a textfile

Tags: database, vba, excel, text-files

```
           K               L           M
    1    Starting_Year    Code        ID
        ------------------------------------
    2    1982            ALLRIN     400200583
    3    1983            ALLRIN     000083522
    4    1983            ALLRIN     400200583
```

Any way to create two text files, there name will be "1982", "1983" according to the "Starting_Year", And "1982" file contains "400200583", also "1983" file contains "000083522" and "400200583".

it is what I had to try ,I am wondering if I have to use a for loop to catch the data from "Starting_Year", "ID"? Any idea, and how I can do it? Big thanks!

```
 Public Function CreateTextFile(FileName As String, Optional Overwrite As Boolean = True, Optional Unicode As Boolean = False) As Scripting.TextStream

    Dim oTs as Scripting.TextStream
    set oTs = CreateTextFile("W:\starting_Year.txt",True)
    oTs.Write("ID")
    oTs.close

    End Function
```

Comment: Please post any attempts you have made.  Also try googling `copy row to another sheet based on criteria vba` then google `save sheet as text file vba`.  this has been answered so many times on this site alone.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.  That way we can help guide you and point out any mistakes/common errors you may be making.  Otherwise, @ScottCraner's got you on the right path.

Comment: Another option might be to use the VBA command `Write` as used in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434220/vba-replacing-commas-in-csv-not-inside-qoutes/35440236#35440236

Comment: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-text-files

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I have edited my question including the code I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub CreateTextFile()
    Dim ifree, iyear, i, j As Long
    Dim ipath As String

```
ipath = "C:\Users\You" 'TO UPDATE

ifree = FreeFile
i = 2
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    iyear = Cells(i, 1)
    ifree = FreeFile
    Open ipath & "\" & iyear & ".txt" For Output As ifree

        j = 2
        While Cells(j, 1) <> ""
            If Cells(j, 1) = iyear Then Print #ifree, Cells(j, 3)
            j = j + 1
        Wend
    Close ifree

i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

With starting_year in Col A, Code in Col B, ID in Col C.

Comment: Thank you!! @crea
it shows "Path not found" when I run it, the error comes from  "Open ipath & "\" & iyear & ".txt" For Output As ifree". need to find the path in different way?

Comment: Just set the var ipath with a real path ;): C:\Users\You