# Split delimiter has to be set to "," but value returned may include a comma

Tags: excel, string, vba, split

I am attempting to run a program which should pull in data from a spreadsheet, split the data in to chunks, and then import it in to my table based on it's "Values" variant.  The format of the data pulled in would look something like this:

"HL","Hecla Mining Company Mining Stock","NSM",12.52,8.69,14.07,6.18

The code for splitting lines, defining values, and assigning them to columns is currently written as follows:

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
    Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim Values As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        sLine = Lines(i)
        If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
            Values = Split(sLine, ",")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Replace(Values(1), Chr(34), "")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Replace(Values(2), Chr(34), "")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Values(3)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(4)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(5)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 9).Value = Values(6)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value = Values(7)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = Values(8)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 13).Value = Values(9)
        End If
```

The issue occurs in that some of the lines return a name that includes a comma within it such as this:

"CDE","Coeur Mining, Inc.","NSM",7.59,16.25,9.52,7.01

This is causing Values(2) = "Coeur Mining" and Value(3) = "Inc." as opposed to Values(2) = "Coeur Mining, Inc." and Values(3) = "NSM"

I have tried updating the code to the following:

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
    Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim Values As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        sLine = Lines(i)
        If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
           ***If InStr(sLine, ",Inc.") Then
            sLine = Replace(sLine, ",inc.", "")
        End If***
            Values = Split(sLine, ",")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Replace(Values(1), Chr(34), "")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Replace(Values(2), Chr(34), "")
            W.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Values(3)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(4)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(5)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 9).Value = Values(6)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value = Values(7)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = Values(8)
            W.Cells(i + 2, 13).Value = Values(9)
        End If
```

However it does not appear to be functioning even with the nested If statement looking for ",Inc." within the sLine string.

Is there a formatting issue that I am not getting? I attempted to use a regex function as well but I am very new to excel/VBA and was unable to get it to figure out how to format it properly.

The regex code that was suggested was given as follows:

```
Public Function splitLine(line As String) As String()

Dim regex As Object     
Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = ",(?=([^" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & "[^" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & ")(?![^" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & "))"
splitLine = Split(regex.Replace(line, ";"), ";") End Function
Values = splitLine(sLine)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, more information or a copy of the actual excel file could be provided upon request.

Comment: I was thinking you were reading a CSV file but, once I actually read the question, I see you are getting information from http.  Try putting the original string into a cell somewhere, and then using Text to Columns specifying that the text is comma-delimited with text delimiters of `"`.  Then work on the cells that Excel has generated, which will correctly leave commas within text strings untouched.

Comment: In the example you give, "Coeur Mining, Inc.", there is a space between the comma and the Inc. Your If statement omits the space. This might make your code work better, but it's not a very general solution. What if you have a law firm, "Dewy, Cheatem, and Howe"? You need a way to detect commas located between pairs of quotes.

Comment: Thank you Rich, I believe you may be right in that it could be the space missing.  I just viewed the web page for the stock and it appears that there is a space in the title.  I will try updating the line of code and see if that has an effect.  Based on what I can see of the 50 symbols that I have put in the only names that return with a "," within the name are incorporated companies.  I agree though, it would be better to find a broader solution which specifically looks for commas within quotes.  Unfortunately I have been attempting that for a few hours and have yet to find a working solution

Comment: YowE3K - I attempted to use a text to columns function for this as well but was unable to get the program to work with it, I am not sure if I didn't have the line in the right location of the code or if there was another issue. Unfortunately as stated in the original post I am very new to anything other than very basic excel functions and have just recently (2 weeks ago) begun attempting to incorporate VBA in to my sheets.  I am typically a fast learner, however I am still so green on the topic that I don't really know how most of the functions I use work, even if I know how to use them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780765/parse-csv-ignoring-commas-inside-string-literals-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going to have to process the string through a 'helper' function that mimics the 'quoted text' parameter of Text-to-Columns.

While inelegant (and likely easily improved upon), this works for your sample.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim str As String, var As Variant

    str = """CDE"",""Coeur Mining, Inc."",""NSM"",7.59,16.25,9.52,7.01"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print str
        str = cleanQuotedCommas(str)
        var = Split(str, Chr(44))
        With .Cells(2, "B").Resize(1, UBound(var) + 1)
            .Value = var
            .Replace what:=ChrW(8203), replacement:=Chr(44), lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace what:=Chr(34), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
            .Value = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function cleanQuotedCommas(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    i = InStr(1, str, Chr(34), vbBinaryCompare)
    Do While CBool(i)
        j = InStr(i + 1, str, Chr(34), vbBinaryCompare)
        k = InStr(i + 1, str, Chr(44), vbBinaryCompare)
        If k > i And k < j Then
            str = Replace(str, Chr(44), ChrW(8203), i, 1, vbBinaryCompare)
        End If
        Debug.Print str
        i = InStr(j + 1, str, Chr(34), vbBinaryCompare)
    Loop
    cleanQuotedCommas = str
End Function
```

[image]

Note the right-alignment of the true numbers for the doubles and the left-alignment of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex-based `SplitLine` function that will return an array of strings. It will exclude the surrounding quotes from those entries that have it, and it will not split on the "included" commas:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function splitLine(line As String) As String()
  Dim regex As Object, matchcol As Object, match As Object
  Dim I As Long, S() As String

Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = """([^""\r\n]*)""|([^,\r\n]+)"
    If .test(line) = True Then
        Set matchcol = .Execute(line)
        ReDim S(0 To matchcol.Count - 1)
        I = 0

        'matches surrounded by quotes will be in 0
        'matches without quotes will be in 1
        For Each match In matchcol
            With match
                S(I) = .submatches(0) & .submatches(1)
            End With
            I = I + 1
        Next match
    End If
End With
splitLine = S
End Function
```